# Are the notifications sounds in Skype configurable based on who is calling, coming on-line etc.?

Tags: skype

In Skype (under `Tools` -> `Options...` -> `Sounds`) I can configure what sounds are played when someone is calling or when one of my contacts comes online.

In order to more easily notice when certain people come online, I would like to configure these notification sounds on a per-contact basis, i.e. assign my contact "Anna" one sound and my contact "Ben" another. This way I could tell by the sound being played whoe came online (even when away from my computer but within earshot). Alternatively, I would like to turn off these notification sounds for all contacts except a select few, so when a sound plays, I know of these people came online.

Is this possible in any version of Skype?

Comment: Let's continue this research and show our support for a native implementation! [Contact Sounds for Skype](http://community.skype.com/t5/Live-Messenger/Contact-Sounds-for-Skype/td-p/1557634)

Answer (score 3):

Based on similar questions asked and feature requests, I don't think it's possible either through Skype or Growl (which is how I get my notifications on Mac OSX). However, if you are a windows user, you might want to look at [Skowler](http://www.skowler.com/), which I came across in my search for a mac equivalent. It advertises customizable "Growl alert on all buddy sign ons or on a per buddy basis." I haven't tried it and don't know anything more about it, but it gets props from me on the basis of the word play alone.

Comment: i wish we had just a skype plugin to do this instead of having to install 2 more applications...